# if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) is fail

Tags: ios, sqlite

On the first implemetation file, all steps

```
- (void) readCitiesFromDatabase {

    databaseName = @"123.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT City_Name, City_Picture, City_Id FROM CITIES, COUNTRIES WHERE CITIES.Country_Id=COUNTRIES.Country_Id AND COUNTRIES.Country_Id = '%@'", self.countryID];

    const char *sqlStatement = [querySQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    // Init the countries Array
    self.cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"success");

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"success");
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSLog(@"success");
                // Read the data from the result row
                char *temp_cName = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0);
                NSString *cName = temp_cName == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:temp_cName];

                char *temp_cPicture = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1);
                NSString *cPicture = temp_cPicture == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:temp_cPicture];

                char *temp_cId = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2);
                NSString *cId = temp_cId == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:temp_cPicture];

                NSMutableDictionary *city = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [city setObject:cName forKey:@"City_Name"];
                [city setObject:cPicture forKey:@"City_Picture"];
                [city setObject:cId forKey:@"City_Id"];

                [self.cities addObject:city];
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);   
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Now I got cities list. When I select a city, I could not see city info.
This is from second implementation.

```
- (void) readCityInfoFromDatabase:(NSString *)querySQL
{
    databaseName = @"123.sqlite";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access

    const char *sqlStatement = [querySQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"success");
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"success");
            if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSLog(@"success");

                char *temp_content = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0);
                [self.cityTextView setText:temp_content == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:temp_content]];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

The first two steps are success but,

```
    if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSLog(@"success");
```

I couldn't see success on this step.

Please help.

Comment: This simply means your query isn't returning any rows. You should not create your query using `stringWithFormat:`. Properly create the query and use the appropriate `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Comment: but in this wise, i got country list and country info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be saving the result of `sqlite3_step()` and checking to see if it is:

- `SQLITE_ROW` = retrieved row of data
- `SQLITE_DONE` = no (more) data to retrieve
- Other = some error occurred

On the basis of what you shared, though, there is a good chance that you simply received `SQLITE_DONE` because there was nothing found. You could get that if there was a mistake in the SQL (e.g. bad join, incorrect `WHERE` clause, etc.). It's hard to say without seeing the SQL used by `readCityInfoFromDatabase` and some representative data from the database.

By the way, not only for `sqlite3_step()`, but rather for all of your `sqlite3_xxx()` calls, if you receive an error, you should be logging `sqlite3_errmsg()`. Right now, if there was an error, you'd have to guess what the source of the problem was.

Comment: Strong emphasis on logging the return code and the sqlite3_errmsg value when you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you, when you wrote the "You could get that if there was a mistake in the SQL (e.g. bad join, incorrect WHERE clause, etc.)", I checked the querySQL and really it was (incorrect where) :) Thanks again and I'll take your advice.

Comment: I am trying to understand the meaning of SQLITE_ROW. According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#row), "The SQLITE_ROW result code returned by sqlite3_step() indicates that another row of output is available." . I am confused by the language. I think how you described the SQLITE_ROW is accurate, but the way they describe it in the official docs makes it sound like that there is another row waiting in the buffer or something.

Comment: In otherwords I think @Rob is right but I am hoping someone can confirm my understanding.

Comment: @Ð.. - See [the `sqlite3_step` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), which says: “If the SQL statement being executed returns any data, then `SQLITE_ROW` is returned [by `sqlite3_step`] each time a new row of data is ready for processing by the caller. The values may be accessed using the [column access functions](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html). `sqlite3_step()` is called again to retrieve the next row of data.” But frankly, if you have any doubt, you don’t need others to confirm this for you. Just try it and verify this empirically.